# AWS get role based credentials in golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-iam

I want to use v4 signing for AWS requests. However, I need the credentials variable to use the signing process.

Now, I can successfully sign the request using id and secret key (which I don't want to do).

I have a lambda function that has a proper permission. So the question is how do I use that permission for my credentials variable?

Here's what I tried using id and key

```
creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(os.Getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"), os.Getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"), "")
signer := v4.NewSigner(creds)
```

and I looked at the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/credentials/

which listed all the methods for creating credentials

- `func NewChainCredentials(providers []Provider) *Credentials`
- `func NewCredentials(provider Provider) *Credentials`
- `func NewEnvCredentials() *Credentials`
- `func NewSharedCredentials(filename, profile string) *Credentials`
- `func NewStaticCredentials(id, secret, token string) *Credentials`
- `func NewStaticCredentialsFromCreds(creds Value) *Credentials`

Which method can I use for my use case?

Comment: In every AWS SDK, the way to use a machine role is to not specify any credentials. Machine role will be assumed by default if one is available on the VM.

Comment: oh but how do I create v4 new signer without specifying the credentials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found another way using session.

```
config := aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String(os.Getenv("AWS_REGION")),
}
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&config))    
signer := v4.NewSigner(sess.Config.Credentials)
```